# How to I select input tag of subiframe in iframe using pure js?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Now I wanna select input tag of sub iframe in iframe.
What is way to select it?

```
 const iframe1 = document.querySelector("#iframe1")
 var iframeDocument1 = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;

 const iframe2 = iframeDocument1.querySelector("#iframe2")
 var iframeDocument2 = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;

 const inputField = iframeDocument2.querySelect("#name")
```

but when I try to get `iframeDocument2`, it get cors errors. How can I dual it?

Error message like below.

```
Error in event handler: Error: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': 
Blocked a frame with origin "https://another-domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

In that case, How can I select it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use *[`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)*

Comment: thanks @mandy8055
could you show me the code using my one, please?

Comment: There's something wrong with your site structure when you have to use nested iframes, but the last error comes from you not having access to change elements on the domain of the last iframe - [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: @Pete , yeah, that's right. first iframe is same domain like website. but sub iframe is not same domain. so it occurs like above errors. but now I can't change any one in website and sub iframe's. in that case, how can I select input tag in another domain's sub iframe?

Comment: If you read the link in my comment, you can only do it by changing your browser settings, but that means it will only work for you

Comment: okay. @Pete now I have no site access for code. so I am trying to select using chrome console. Following your article, I can't select input tag of subframe in iframe when iframe's domain is different. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah you probably would not be able to access it if it's not your domain

Comment: @Pete Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256558/discussion-between-glistenstar-and-pete).